# Removing the title post in wordpress so I can use it as a static CMS

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

so basically I want to manage a simple static website. My template is pretty much `<?php get_header ?>` and `<?php get_footer ?>` with the loop in between those. My goal is to be able to create pages and posting the HTML code, effectively between the header and footer. But whenever I post I get this of course:

"Test
October 1st, 2012 by admin
testest
Posted in"

I don't know enough PHP to modify the loop code itself which I tried doing. I also tried making a functions.php that had this:

```
<?php 
add_action('genesis_before', 'child_conditional_actions');
function child_conditional_actions() {
if ( is_page() )
remove_action('genesis_post_title', 'genesis_do_post_title');
}
?>
```

But it did nothing. Does anyone have any advice?

This is the full loop code I used in case anyone's curious:
http://pastie.org/4894413

Comment: Im not sure what your trying to achieve exactly - do you want to have all the content from your pages display on one page or would you still like them on their own pages?

Comment: My goal is to have the header and footer as a theme, and to be able to post the content itself in HTML, through wordpress. So if I needed to create a new page I would simply make one in wordpress use the header/footer template, and post the HTML of the rest of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Loop is what's outputting your "Test" posts. Anyplace there is a loop, WordPress will insert one or more posts.

You can remove bits of The Loop to suit your preference, so removing `the_time()` would stop the time from showing, removing `the_content()` will take out the post body/excerpt, etc. It can be moderately complicated to understand at first, but it's a totally fine thing to do.

If you want a truly static page, with the WP header and footer but completely raw HTML in the middle, you could even The Loop out entirely. So pretty much `<?php get_header() ?>`, then your static HTML code, and finally `<?php get_footer() ?>`. Bear in mind that you'll lose a lot of the usefulness of WordPress by doing that, and it may cause some oddities with the page's  tag, etc.

Comment: That's true Scott. I don't want to end up making 80 separate templates for each page either I'd rather make 80 pages with 1 or 2 templates, which is why I'm trying out WP in the first place. I've isolated it to this:  http://pastie.org/4894855  But now this code is wrecking my page layout, so something is wrong here. I changed the class to a container DIV instead that I've styled but even if I keep the previous entry class the result is a broken layout.

Comment: This is embarrassing.... I used comments in the HTML to organize the code a little but apparently those got through somehow.....

Comment: The Loop from this pastie should work in its current state, assuming all the tags from your header/footer balance out as well. Useful tip: if you want to hide your template comments from showing up in an end-user's View Source window, you can use `<?php /* PHP comments */ ?>` instead of `<!-- HTML comments -->`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is paste html code between get_header(); and get_footer(); everything can be removed from the loop with the exception of the_content();. The below code is a modifcation of your pastie code

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Be wary of any structural elements removed (divs etc), but now any code you place in your content box in your admin console will show up on your pages. It should also be noted that copying code into Wordpress' html view of a post/page is not always a good idea en mass as Wordpress likes to 'clean; the code in some cases. If this occurs, you could use a snippet plugin, basically a shortcode generator.

I have used http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/embedit-pro/ in the past for a client.

Hope this helps,

Jamie